# How do I solve $\frac {(x^3-4x^2+5x-6)}{(x^2-x-6)}$ using long division?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to solve $\frac {(x^3-4x^2+5x-6)}{(x^2-x-6)}$ using long division...

$x^2-x-6$ / $x^3 -4x^2+5x-6$ \ $x-3 $

$\underline{x^3 - x^2 - 6x}$    -

$-3x^2$

$\underline{-3x^2-3x-18}$ -

$4x+12$

---

I made some mistake here... How do I solve this step-by-step?

Comment: @amWhy are you sure that is correct? See also Alijah's answer.

Comment: I spotted a later error, and tried to correct your subsequent work. Alijah found an earlier error that I missed, and correctly went on from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the image below for the long division process - sign changes due to subtraction are highlighted in red. 
[image]